# Insert a digit to maximize the given number

Tags: python, interview-questions

Was asked in an interview today -

You are given an integer (in finite range [-N, N]) and you wish to maximize the number by inserting somewhere the digit '5'.

My solution - the idea here is going from left to right and checking if the digit is bigger than 5 or not. The first time you reach one that isn't you insert the 5 there. With the exception of negative numbers where you check and do the opposite.

I did it by converting ints to strings and vice versa.

```
def solution(N):
    array = str(N)
    result = []
    mod = 1
    for i in range(len(array) + 1):
        if i == len(array):
            result.append('5')
            break

        if array[i] == '-':
            mod = -1
            result.append(array[i])
            continue

        if int(array[i]) * mod > 5 * mod:
            result.append(array[i])
        else:
            result.append('5')
            result.append(array[i:])
            break

    return int("".join(result))
```

So - `solution(128)` will output `5128`; `solution(0)` will output `50`, `solution(-74)` will output `-574` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, `if array[i] == '-'` is meant to check if the number is negative. Having it like you have though doesn't make a lot of sense. If it's in the loop, that suggests that a `-` could be expected at any point within the number. In reality though, it will only ever occur as the first character in the string. I'd just check `N` the number with `if N < 0` to see if it's negative. You can streamline this check right in the definition of `mod`:

```
mod = 1 if N >= 0 else -1
```

Unfortunately, that slightly complicates adding `-` to `result`. The simplest way to deal with it I think is just to change the definition of `result` to be similar to that of `mod`:

```
result = [] if n >= 0 else ['-']
```

Since the checks are the same though, you could combine then into returning a tuple instead then unpacking it:

```
mod, result = (1, []) if n >= 0 else (-1, ['-'])
```

And, `array` will need to have the `-` cleaved off if we're doing it before the loop:

```
mod, result, checked_digits = (1, [], digits) if n >= 0 else (-1, ['-'], digits[1:])
```

Normally, I don't think a triple variable definition like this should be encouraged, but there's nothing too fancy or complicated going on here to make the line confusing. I think it's fine.

---

I'd rename `array` and `N`:

- `array` isn't really a correct or useful description. I think `digits` would be better.
- `N` should be `n`.

---

You're iterating over the indices of `digits` and using `digits[i]` all over the place even though you don't even need the index in most cases. I'd iterate over the digits themselves, and use `enumerate` to get the index in the couple cases that you actually need it for:

```
for i, digit in enumerate(digits):
    . . .

    if int(digit) * mod > 5 * mod:
        result.append(digit)
```

---

I'd move the `if i == len(array):` check out of the loop as well. Really, it's just checking if at no point a `break` was encountered. That's exactly the use case for `for`'s `else` clause [(yes, `for` can have an `else`)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
for i, digit in enumerate(checked_digits):
    . . .

else:
    result.append(5)
```

The `else` will only execute if no `break` was encountered. In the case of this code, that means that no digit greater than `5` was found.

Honestly, this is the first time I've ever found a useful case for `for...else`. It worked out nice here though.

---

I'd add `5` and `'5'` as constants at the top. Having the magic strings and numbers floating your code makes your code harder to change latter, and doesn't indicate what the `5` and `'5'` actually are for:

```
TARGET_NUM = 5
TARGET_DIGIT = str(TARGET_NUM)


def solution(n):
```

Or, just make that number a parameter with a default to make it easy to use different target numbers:

```
def solution(n: int, target_num: int = 5) -> int:
    target_digit = str(target_num)
```

I also added some type hints in there, because why not?

---

---

In the end, this is what I ended up with:

```
def solution(n: int, target_num: int = 5):
    target_digit = str(target_num)
    digits = str(n)

    mod, result, checked_digits = (1, [], digits) if n >= 0 else (-1, ['-'], digits[1:])

    for i, digit in enumerate(checked_digits):
        if int(digit) * mod > TARGET_NUM * mod:
            result.append(digit)

        else:
            result.append(TARGET_DIGIT)
            result.append(checked_digits[i:])
            break

    else:
        result.append(TARGET_DIGIT)

    return int("".join(result))
```

Comment: thanks for the input. Never knew about the for-else thingy